# Xcode, choose menu of File, Add Packages, cannot load Github projects

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I am using Xcode to add Swift Packages from Github, but it always show loading and loading...

Please see the bellowing picture.

[Package loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8GP5.png)